# Stability of molecule based on ring size

Tags: ring-strain

During a discussion on chemically valid molecules based on atom valency, I was told that in molecules like

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

although the sum of the bonds that are incident to each atom do not surpass their valence capacity, it would have to be very far from the optimal geometry as predicted by [VSEPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSEPR_theory) to have the represented atomic bonds. In addition, it was suggested that molecules with 3-member rings in general would be very energetically unstable. I was wondering if this is true and if you could expand more on this. Pointing me to the appropriate literature would also be appreciated.

---

EDITS:

Here is another set of molecules from [an article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03480) that pass validity based on valency. Are these invalid just because of having 3-member rings as well?

[image]

Comment: @Mithoron 1,1,1-propellane is a thing, though.

Comment: Cyclopropane is very strained, but it does exist (and is used as an anaesthetic). Many derivatives exist but whether many *fused* cyclopropanes exist is probably stretching things. I'm guessing, though.

Comment: :/ Somehow permeakra got my point. It doesn't matter if there's cyclopropane ring. Even fused isn't necessarily a problem, but there's a pyramidal carbon there! And hydroxyl next to it... Good luck trying to make it!

Comment: Cyclopropane ring itself isn't all that bad, it has enthalpy of formation of 53.30 kJ/mol, same as ethylene.  It's not excellent, but it is't much. Fused cyclopropanes are not great, but byciclobutane exists. The problems start when one considers strongly strained double bonds and pyramidal carbons (when all four bonds are directed into same half-sphere).  Some compounds with pyramidal carbons are isolable (like 1,1,1-propellane), but usually because of some specific gimmick of this particular system slowing down its decay.

Comment: @permeakra So as a rule of thumb, I was told to forbid all 3-member cycles, 4-member cycles containing a double bond and all cycles containing a triple bond. Do these constraints make sense?

Comment: @Blade Not really except for triple bond. Triple bond in small (<8) cycles is really unstable. But for 8+ membered cycles it's perfectly OK. There is not, regrettably, wide-scale rules of thumb.